# How to filter single value from column which is comma separated in data flow ADF

Tags: azure, filter, azure-data-factory

I have a source column which contains some code. The column 'Code' can have single value or comma separated multiple values. example:

1. Code= FA1
2. Code=FA1,MD2
3. Code=GH2,FA1

Now my requirement is to apply filter after source in Data Flow and fetch only those rows which contains FA1.

I cannot use equal as I have to look for row which contain FA1, and my source column is string type not array.
I tried in()/instr() and contains function but it did not work for me.

Can anyone please help me to find the correct solution to filter.

Comment: When you apply filter , Do you want to get only the first row out of these three rows?

Comment: No, I want all 3 rows because they contain the Code FA1

Comment: Give the expression as  `like(Code, '%FA1%')` in "Filter on" text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the  `like`  function in **filter transformation** to filter rows based on a specific value in a string column that may contain multiple values separated by commas. In this case, you can use the  `%`  wildcard character to match any number of characters before or after the value "FA1" in the "Code" column.

Below is the example of how you can use the  `like`  function in a Filter transformation to filter rows that contain the value "FA1" in the "Code" column:

- Add a Filter transformation to your Data Flow after the source transformation.  In the Filter transformation, Give the expression as  `like(Code, '%FA1%')` in "Filter on" text box.

  [image]

**Output of filter transformation:**
This expression matches any rows where the "Code" column contains the value "FA1" anywhere in the string.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Aswin! much appreciated for the help